# Using Laplace transform to solve $y'(t)+y(t-1)=t^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I am quite stuck with the following differential equation:
$$y'(t)+y(t-1)=t^2 \quad \text{with} \: y(t)=0 \; \text{for} \; t\leq 0.$$
I would like to use Laplace transform to solve this one. Using different properties I manage to find the following relation:
$$p \, Y(p)+e^{-p} \, Y(p)=\frac{2}{p^3}$$
Isolating $Y(p)$,
$$Y(p)=\frac{2}{p^3(p+e^{-p})}=\frac{2}{p^4}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{e^{-p}}{p}}$$
But now I am stuck, I think I would like to express the solution as a series but I can't find the series expansion of the right member.

Anyone has a clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try expressing it as a "geometric series".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I tried but here is what I have :
$$Y(p)=\frac{2}{p^4}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{e^{-p}}{p}\right)^n$$
So,
$$Y(p)=\frac{2}{p^4}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\frac{p^{k-1}}{k!}\right)^n$$
But it seems to lead nowhere...

Comment: $$\frac{2}{p^4}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{e^{-p}}{p}\right)^n=\frac{2}{p^4}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\frac{e^{-np}}{p^n}$$

Comment: Yes sure, now I guess I can go for,
$$L^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{-np}}{p^n}\right)=\frac{(t-n)^{n-1}\theta(t-n)}{\Gamma(n)}$$

Comment: Well, first of all notice that the Laplace transform of $\text{y}\left(t-\alpha\right)$ is given by:

$$\mathscr{L}_t\left[\text{y}\left(t-\alpha\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\exp\left(-\alpha\text{s}\right)\left(\mathscr{L}_t\left[\text{y}\left(t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}+\int\limits_{-\alpha}^0\exp\left(-\text{s}t\right)\text{y}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\right)\tag1$$